# How can I JSON parse this into a JSON object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I pass a `$input.json('$')` body from the apigateway which is `x-application/urlencoded` to a Lambda function and insert into a Dynamodb. The `event.body` is like this

[image: event.body]

How can I unescape this string and get the JSON object?
I've tried `JSON.parse()` and something like `.replace slashes` but it didn't work.

Comment: use Json.parse () twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [$util.parseJson()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference)

**EDIT:** 
Example:

```
#set ($bodyObj = $util.parseJson($input.body))
```

then use it :

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Mytable",
    "Item": {
    "commentId": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
            },
        "pageId": {
            "S": "bodyObj.pageId"
            },
        "userName": {
            "S": "bodyObj.userName)"
        },
        "message": {
            "S": bodyObj.message"
        }
    }
}
```

example modified from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-api-gateway-mapping-improvements/

also might be worth checking the https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Comment: sorry, but,how do you write in the template?I am tring "body": $util.parseJson($input.body),but get the could not parse json response.

Comment: Edited the answer with extra examples

Answer (score 0):

I use the json.loads and json.dump functions.
And I get the same kind of string in DynamoDB whenever I store something